# Playing videos sequentially

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, video-streaming

I want to play video in WP7.

This is my code:

```
 MediaPlayerLauncher player = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
            player.Media = new Uri("video link", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            player.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
            player.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
            player.Show();
```

This is working fine.

After finishing this video I want to continue playing another video. I want to play two videos one after another.

Is this possible in WP7? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title asks how to play videos in general. Are you aware of the [`MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)? It can be used to play back video as well and it has an event telling you when [video playback ends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). And it can also give you the [video length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=rickyt&y=2010&m=08&d=20&WeblogPostName=mediaelement-mediaplayerlauncher-and-applicationbar-in-windows-phone&GroupKeys=) has an example of both `MediaElement` and `MediaPlayerLauncher`.

Answer (score 0):

The [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher.show%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) does not expose an event or callback for you to find out if and/or when the video has ended. I am afraid it is not possible to hook into these events.

Comment: this is not possible ha? i want to get video length it is possible or not.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think it is possible.